# PinCodeTextField desnot become editable on tap

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Once OTP is typed in designated fields if user wants to update any particular digit, boxes are not editable if  clicks on any particular box **PinCodeTextField**

This is my code-snippet.

```dart
    PinCodeTextField(
                autovalidateMode: _autoValidateMode,
                focusNode: _otpNode,
                appContext: context,
                controller: _otpController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                animationType: AnimationType.scale,
                animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                length: 6,
                enableActiveFill: true,
                pinTheme: PinTheme(
                  shape: PinCodeFieldShape.box,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                  fieldHeight: 40,
                  fieldWidth: 40,
                  activeFillColor: Color(0xFFFeaedf0),
                  activeColor: Color(0xFFFeaedf0),
                  inactiveFillColor: Color(0xFFFeaedf0),
                  inactiveColor: Color(0xFFFeaedf0),
                  selectedColor: Color(0xFFFeaedf0),
                  selectedFillColor: Color(0xFFFeaedf0),
                ),
                onChanged: (pin) {
                  _pin = pin;
                },
                validator: (v) {
                  if (v.toString().isEmpty || v!.length != 6) {
                    return "Please enter valid pincode".tr;
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
```

Comment: share your code to get better answer

Comment: Can you include the package name?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/pin_code_fields

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 custom ways to do it however you like you can use the code.

Method 1 - Fits the best I think

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OtpForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const OtpForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OtpFormState createState() => _OtpFormState();
}

class _OtpFormState extends State<OtpForm> {
  late FocusNode pin2FocusNode;
  late FocusNode pin3FocusNode;
  late FocusNode pin4FocusNode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pin2FocusNode = FocusNode();
    pin3FocusNode = FocusNode();
    pin4FocusNode = FocusNode();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    pin2FocusNode.dispose();
    pin3FocusNode.dispose();
    pin4FocusNode.dispose();
  }

  void nextField(String value, FocusNode focusNode) {
    if (value.length == 1) {
      focusNode.requestFocus();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Form(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(height: 50),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      obscureText: true,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        nextField(value, pin2FocusNode);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      focusNode: pin2FocusNode,
                      obscureText: true,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      onChanged: (value) => nextField(value, pin3FocusNode),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      focusNode: pin3FocusNode,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      onChanged: (value) => nextField(value, pin4FocusNode),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      focusNode: pin4FocusNode,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        if (value.length == 1) {
                          pin4FocusNode.unfocus();
                          // Then you need to check is the code is correct or not
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Method 2 - Doesn't fits well as compared to Method 1 but does the job

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class EnterOTP extends StatelessWidget {
  const EnterOTP({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: const [
              OTPDigitTextFieldBox(first: true, last: false),
              OTPDigitTextFieldBox(first: false, last: false),
              OTPDigitTextFieldBox(first: false, last: false),
              OTPDigitTextFieldBox(first: false, last: true),
            ],
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OTPDigitTextFieldBox extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool first;
  final bool last;
  const OTPDigitTextFieldBox(
      {Key? key, required this.first, required this.last})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 85,
      child: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 1.0,
        child: TextField(
          autofocus: true,
          onChanged: (value) {
            if (value.length == 1 && last == false) {
              FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
            }
            if (value.isEmpty && first == false) {
              FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
            }
          },
          showCursor: false,
          readOnly: false,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          maxLength: 1,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            // contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            counter: const Offstage(),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                  width: 2,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.black),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            hintText: "",
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Up-to you to choose whichever suits you best.

Comment: unable to edit any random digit. when tab to edit any digit, cursor moved to last entered digit. Please provide solution to move cursor to clicked digit using above package.

Comment: I've changed my answer sorry for the previous one. You may check these one's and if found helpful mark my answer as correct. Any question about them you can ask me